# List the number of records that have X number of associations in has_many

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have my Person class which will have 0 or more widgets associated

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :widgets
end
```

I'd like to list out the number of People that have X widgets i.e:

```
Num of widgets | Num of people
0              | 10
1              | 34
2              | 0
...
100            | 20
```

(which is saying 34 people have 1 widget, etc).

Here's my best effort so far:

```
Person.joins(:widgets).group('people.id').select('people.id, count(widget_id) as widget_count').group('widget_count')
```

But I receive

```
 Mysql2::Error: Can't group on 'widget_count'
```

Comment: you can see the sql that is produced by adding .to_sql behind your statement and learn a lot of that or try that sql in a database client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The raw SQL query should look like this (tested in PostgreSQL):

```
SELECT a.widget_count, COUNT(a.widget_count) FROM 
(SELECT p.id, COUNT(w.id) AS widget_count FROM Person p JOIN Widget w ON w.person_id = p.id GROUP BY p.id) 
AS a 
GROUP BY a.widget_count
```

Comment: Perfect, used that with `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all` and got what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you very much with the syntax as this is not my strong suite. But knowing SQL you might want to swap the count around.
What you are counting are actually the people.id's.

Hopefully this helps your line of thought.

Comment: really? i'm doing count(widget_id) so not sure thats true? anyhow if you could do it in SQL I might be able to translate to rails syntax!

Comment: Well actually you are right. But it gets confusing.
You want to count the amount of people having COUNT(widgets)

This is beyond me. With sql i would do a subquery with your logic to get all people and their counts, then use the result of that subquery to get the range of widget coutns and count the people.